# storing form data using ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to store my form data using ajax but it gives me error.
I'm submitting form data in js file which calls another php file to perform insert operation.
here is my code:

```
  <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" >Create an Account</button>
```

clicking on that button it calls the js file
**serve.js**

```
 function myFunction(){


           var name = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
            var lname = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
            var mail = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var password =document.getElementById("password").value;

            var confpass= document.getElementById("passwordConfirmation").value;

                   // var dataString = 'name1=' + name + '&email1=' + email + '&password1=' + password + '&contact1=' + contact;
            if(password != confpass)
            {
                alert ('password doesnot match!');
            }

            // var form_data = $('#edit_user').serialize();
         var datastring= 'name1=' + name + 'name2=' + lname +'email='+mail+ 'pass='+password;

           $.ajax({
        url: "learnapi.php",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {type: "signup", datastring:datastring },
        //type: should be same in server code, otherwise code will not run
        ContentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
};
```

Through ajax request it perform insert operation
**learnapi.php**

```
<?php
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("learnapp");
if(isset($_GET['type']))
{
   $res = [];


  if($_GET['type'] =="signup"){
    $name  = $_GET ['name1'];
    $lname = $_GET['name2'];

    $passW = $_GET['pass'];
  //  $passW1 = $_GET['Pass1'];
    $mail  = $_GET ['email'];



    $query1  = "insert into signup(firstname,lastname,password,email) values('$name','$lname','$passW','$mail')";
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

    if($result1)
    {
        $res["flag"] = true;
        $rest["message"] = "Data Inserted Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        $res["flag"] = false;
        $rest["message"] = "Oppes Errors";
    }
    } 


else{
$res["flag"] = false;
$rest["message"] = "Invalid format";
    }

 echo json_encode($rest);
}  
?>
```

It gives me error as:
[image: error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the onclick attribute and use a event listener

```
$('#submit').on('click',myFunction(event));
```

Change data to

```
 data: JSON.stringify({type: "signup",name1:name ,name2:lname,email:mail,pass:password});
```

prevent the submit add this to you function

```
event.preventDefault();
```

add this to you php page

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

change the syntax try using mysqli or pdo, the current syntax isn't used any more

Comment: I changed it but now it doesn't reflect any messages

Comment: I ran my php file it shows nothing I also use var_dump($_GET); But it shows nothing. How do I check that my ajax request is performed.

Comment: go to developer tools, see your picture , there is a XHR tab click on it, then click on submit .if a request appeared in that XHR tab that means you ajax was triggered, there you can see what the ajax returned

Comment: are you getting any alert when you are clicking the submit button or is just refreshing the page?

Comment: add event.preventDefault(); in your function or in the onclick attribute after the function to prevent the page refresh and allow the ajax to run

Comment: remove the onclick attribute, use a event listener, se my updated answer

Comment: thanks @madalin it works for me >thanks for your valuable time

Comment: but my data is not inserted into database it reflect as {"readyState":4,"responseText":"\r\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: paste a screenshot of the XHR request body

Comment: {"type":"signup","name1":"sachin","name2":"mathur","email":"sach_math@gmail.com","pass":"1230"}:""

Comment: use mysqli or pdo,make sure you have no errors in learnapi.php

Comment: I checked the json response it shows error as:syntax error:json.parse:unexpected end of data at line 2 column 1 of json data

Answer (score 0):

your passing of parameters is wrong. replace your ajax data with the following and remove your "var datastring".

```
data: {type: "signup", name1: name,name2:lname,email:mail,pass:password },
```

Comment: I chaged it but now it doesnt reflect any messages.

Comment: ajax request is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

instead of json data use post data in ajax method

```
$.ajax({
    url: "learnapi.php",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {type: "signup", datastring:datastring },
    //type: should be same in server code, otherwise code will not run
    ContentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Use post method just giving you idea

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function xxx(x1,x2)
    {
        $.post(
            "yy.php", // target post file
            {data: data, display: display,user: user,password: password}, 
    .......
  </script>
```

In learnapi.php
Use $_POST method instead of $_GET method

Comment: you forgot to mention that he should change from $_GET to $_POST in php